# Error "ssl handshake failure" when use docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ssl, containers, docker-swarm

I have a application that written with Java (spring-boot). When run it manually (with `java -jar` command) it's working fine without any problem.
But when use docker container (docker image built based alpine and use docker containers in docker swarm) it doesn't work and my app couldn't send request out and get error "SSL Handshake failure"

I checked it in `--network host` docker and had a same result. Also I built new docker image and imported cert file in java cacerts and /etc/ssl/certs in alpine but it did not work. In addition to when run manually my app I don't import any cert file in host.

Can anyone help in this case?

Thanks,
Hamid

Comment: Hi Hamid,
I'm also running into same issue, I did not check with host property, but I can tell you that the api service is available from swagger-ui but not from an UI client or curl call.
curl error:
curl -k -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://devappserver-api:8585/api/v1/actuator/env'
curl: (35) error:140943F2:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert unexpected message.

Did you find any solution/docs that can help, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use network mode: bridge or host to fix this SSL error.

Still error on docker overlay network:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  httpstest:
    hostname: httpstest
    container_name: httpstest
    image: httpstest-service:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
    ports:
      - "8288:8080"
networks:
  default:
    name: kaio_io
    driver: bridge
#    driver: overlay
#    driver: host
```